# Datatables throwing error on window resize

Tags: jquery, webforms, datatables

I have a DataTable.

When I set it, I get no errors, the table is properly generated, but then whenever I resize the window, I'm getting this error:

> **0x800a138f** - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'style'
>   of undefined or null reference

I don't think I can reproduce the code here, but I can guarantee that the table structure is correct.

This is what I'm using to create the DataTable:

```
function initDataTable() {
    if ($.fn.dataTable.isDataTable($('#grdPrincipal'))) {
        $('#grdPrincipal').DataTable().destroy();
        initDataTable();
    } else {
        $("#grdPrincipal")
            .DataTable({
                scrollY: 210,
                scrollX: true,
                fixedHeader: true,
                fixedColumns: true,
                paging: false,
                info: false,
                searching: false
            });
    }
}
```

Since I'm using a UpdatePanel in my asp.net webforms project, I have to run this code whenever I do a postback, because the table is rebuilt every time.

There are no problems with postbacks or anything, as I said, the only problem is when I resize the window.

What could it be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try destroying the datatable before you update your updatePanel, like this:

```
var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
    function BeginRequestHandler(sender, args) {
        //Runs before updatePanel starts updating
        $('#grdPrincipal').DataTable().destroy();
    }

    function EndRequestHandler(sender, args) {
        initDataTable();
        //Runs after updatePanel has finished updating
    }
    prm.add_beginRequest(BeginRequestHandler);
    prm.add_endRequest(EndRequestHandler);
```

Comment: I have done something different here and I have noticed that the first time the dataTable is created, I can resize the window as I wish, but after the updatePanel is reloaded, this error is thrown if I resize the window. When the updatePanel is reloaded, the table is rebuilt so it's not a datatable anymore.

Comment: I have this -> `function pageLoad() { initDataTable(); }`

Comment: Hmm looks like you need another event callback.. the ".resize()" jQuery's feature. I'm writing it in my post, take a look in 1 minute.

Comment: Take a look now, hope it helps

Comment: This actually kind of ruined my table. It's duplicating the rows.

Comment: I tried messing around and now I'm getting **Unable to get property 'top' of undefined or null reference**

Comment: It's strange, if it loses the datatable state you are registering and solving it.. You could verify some particularities that the datatable could have like a class or another attribute, if this attribution exists you just ignore the call.

Comment: It has some classes but they are only bootstrap classes like table-hover, etc

Comment: Actually, it didn't duplicate the rows. My bad. It just got rid of the fixed header and the fixed column is acting weird.

Comment: What's the issue since you have registered the script on pageload() and coded the resize callback?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122540/discussion-between-phiter-fernandes-and-rodrigo-quinones-pichioli).